# How is it possible to see the full list of **actually** supported style attributes of any control for Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, documentation

How is it possible to see the full list of **actually** supported style attributes of any control for Android?

*For example, I'm trying to see what I can attributes I can set in the style for `ActionMenuView` control:*

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView
        android:id="@+id/toolbarLeft"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

*For example, I can't figure out if it's supposed to support `android:gravity` attribute. I don't see any difference applying it.*

I want to know where I can find the full list of supported attributes. It seems that Android documentation doesn't include that information: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/ActionMenuView

Answer (score 0):

For Gravity you can't.  Because Gravity isn't an attribute of the view, its an attribute of how it fits into the parent view.  So really it depends on whether the parent view supports it or not.  Same for layout_weight, layout_width, layout_height, and margins, among others.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is about the list of supported attributes - not just about the example...

Comment: The answer is look at the android documentation-  but it won't include anything that's looked at by parents so it will always be incomplete. Taken that way its also off topic for this site-  requests for outside resources are off topic.

Comment: But I can't find the list of the supported attributes in the Android documentation. It shows only supported methods, constants and fields: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/ActionMenuView

Comment: Then one doesn't exist.  The documentation for support library classes is a little less complete.

Comment: Does it exist for other classes?

Comment: Some.  For example, EditText https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText   Of course it still won't include properties that have to do with parents/children, as previously discussed.

Comment: You can also see it for the non-support version:  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ActionMenuView.  But they didn't bother adding it for the support library

Comment: From the documentation of `ActionMenuView`: `android:gravity` - Specifies how an object should position **its content**, on both the X and Y axes, within its own bounds.

Answer (score 0):

`ActionMenuView` just extends `LinearLayoutCompat` and it doesn't have any special attributes in it. you can see the original source below.

```
/**
 * ActionMenuView is a presentation of a series of menu options as a View. It provides
 * several top level options as action buttons while spilling remaining options over as
 * items in an overflow menu. This allows applications to present packs of actions inline with
 * specific or repeating content.
 */
public class ActionMenuView extends LinearLayoutCompat implements MenuBuilder.ItemInvoker,
        MenuView {

    private static final String TAG = "ActionMenuView";

    static final int MIN_CELL_SIZE = 56; // dips
    static final int GENERATED_ITEM_PADDING = 4; // dips

    private MenuBuilder mMenu;

    /** Context against which to inflate popup menus. */
    private Context mPopupContext;

    /** Theme resource against which to inflate popup menus. */
    private int mPopupTheme;

    private boolean mReserveOverflow;
    private ActionMenuPresenter mPresenter;
    private MenuPresenter.Callback mActionMenuPresenterCallback;
    MenuBuilder.Callback mMenuBuilderCallback;
    private boolean mFormatItems;
    private int mFormatItemsWidth;
    private int mMinCellSize;
    private int mGeneratedItemPadding;

    OnMenuItemClickListener mOnMenuItemClickListener;

    public ActionMenuView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public ActionMenuView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setBaselineAligned(false);
        final float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        mMinCellSize = (int) (MIN_CELL_SIZE * density);
        mGeneratedItemPadding = (int) (GENERATED_ITEM_PADDING * density);
        mPopupContext = context;
        mPopupTheme = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-support version of classes has more information in documentation, including supported XML attributes. For example: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ActionMenuView

But it seems, for support version of the corresponding classes the attributes can just not work.

Comment: Google is the same as chaos.